# add new checkbox in checkboxlist using jquery and access that checkbox in C# code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I have create one web part in sharepoint 2010. In CreateChildControls() method i write following code.

```
 Panel pnlPropertyDiv;
    Button btnEmployee;
    CheckBoxList plist;
    CheckBoxList rlist;
    HtmlGenericControl divleft = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    HtmlGenericControl divmiddle = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {


            plist = new CheckBoxList();
            plist.ID = "ProjectCheckbox";
            plist.Items.Add("p");
            plist.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

            rlist = new CheckBoxList();
            rlist.ID = "ResourceCheckbox";
            rlist.Items.Add("r");
            rlist.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

            Panel pnlContainer = new Panel();
            pnlContainer.ID = "Project_Container";
            this.Controls.Add(pnlContainer);
            pnlPropertyDiv = new Panel();


            divleft.ID = "left";
            divleft.Attributes["style"] = "float:left; border-right: 1px solid #E1E3E4;height: 65px;text-align: center;width: 200px;";
            pnlPropertyDiv.Controls.Add(divleft);
            divleft.Controls.Add(plist);


            divmiddle.ID = "middle";
            divmiddle.Attributes["style"] = "float:left; border-right: 1px solid #E1E3E4;height: 65px;text-align: center;width: 200px;";
            pnlPropertyDiv.Controls.Add(divmiddle);
            divmiddle.Controls.Add(rlist);

            HtmlGenericControl divfooter = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            divfooter.ID = "footer";
            divfooter.Attributes["style"] = "text-align: center";
            btnEmployee = new Button();
            btnEmployee.ID = "btnEmployee";
            btnEmployee.Text = "Apply";
            btnEmployee.Click += new EventHandler(btnEmployee_Click);
            divfooter.Controls.Add(btnEmployee);
            pnlPropertyDiv.Controls.Add(divfooter);
            pnlPropertyDiv.ID = "EditProperties";
            pnlPropertyDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 410px;position:fixed;top:45px;right:18px;z-index:1;color: #6C6E70;font-family: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size: 8pt;");
            this.Controls.Add(pnlPropertyDiv);


    }
```

using jquery i add new checkbox in checkbox list.Below is my button event code.

```
        project = "";
        resource = "";
        foreach (ListItem pclist in plist.Items)
        {
            if (pclist.Selected == true)
            {
                project += pclist.Text;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        foreach (ListItem rclist in rlist.Items)
        {
            if (rclist.Selected == true)
            {
                resource += rclist.Text;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

My problem is when i click my button i am not able to get checkbox which is added by jquery.Because CreateChildControls() method always call first and override checkboxlist control so changes apply by jquery is override.

**Note:-**

**I am not able to use ispostback because CreateChildControls() have must call when page refresh.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced you will beable to access the checkbox added by jquery within the c# code behind. The jquery checkbox won't be added to the .Net control tree so won't be accessible to any server side processing.

You can do the other way. Add a control in C# then access through JQuery. Standard stuff.

Could you put the control in a div with style="display:none" set then use JQuery to show it.

```
$('#PanelClientID').show()
```

That might work for you?